# Mapping cylinder being mobius band - example 1.35 in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology

A lot of the geometric examples in Hatcher with abstract identification spaces I have a hard time visualizing. In the following example, Hatcher says that the mapping cylinder of $z \to z^2$ is the Mobius strip, however, I don't see how this works. Geometrically, this seems hard to visualize, and since I have encountered similar problems with visualizations before, I would like to ask: how does one see this mathematically and what is the useful way to view these kinds of geometric realizations when solving problems?

Here is the excerpt:

[image]

Comment: What is Hatcher's primary definition of the Möbius band?

Answer (score 1):

One way of visualizing this is using the idea of regular value theorem. Think the circle as a smooth manifold. The map given by $z \mapsto z^2$ is a smooth map. Now you have to visualize the domain in such a way so that each point remains a regular point, i.e. keep the smooth structure of the circle. The domain is compact, so for each $y \in S^1, f^{-1}(y)$ is a finite discrete subset of $S^1$. Here each $y \in S^1$ has two preimages. So you have to visualize the domain circle in such a way so that each pair of points{ $z,-z$} have same image. This leads to folding the circle in this way.
[image]

Now the blue circle is your domain $S^1 \times \{0\}$ and the black circle is the image identified as $S^1 \times \{1\}$. Now for each $z$, identify the points $f(z)$ and $f(-z)$ in the black circle. And you get the Möbius strip.